# Can you have two print statements in the default part of a switch

Tags: java, printing, switch-statement

Title says it all. Can you have two print statements inside a default in a switch. If so how would you do it?

For example:
default: System.out.println ("Hello");
Could I have another print statement in that line or no?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just try it and see what happens?

Comment: I did, and it didn't work. I'm new to this and I'm trying my best okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you have two print statement in the default part of a switch.

**Yes.** You'd add another `print` statement. It doesn't have to be on the same line.

```
default: 
    System.out.println ("Hello");
    System.out.println ("Hello, Again");
```

Comment: Wow that was easy! Thanks, I knew I had to be missing something easy